# How do I sort a hash table in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, hashtable

I have a Javascript hash table, like so:

```
var things = [ ];
things["hello"] = {"name" : "zzz I fell asleep", "number" : 7};
things["one"] = {"name" : "something", "number" : 18};
things["two"] = {"name" : "another thing", "number" : -2};
```

I want to sort these into order by name, so if I iterate through the hash table it will go in order

```
another thing
something
zzz I fell asleep
```

I tried doing this:

```
function compareThings(thing1, thing2) {
    var name1 = thing1["name"].toLowerCase();
    var name2 = thing2["name"].toLowerCase();
    if (name1 < name2) {
        return -1;
        }
    if (name1 > name2) {
        return 1;
        }
    return 0;
}

things.sort(compareThings);
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Edit: it occurs to me that perhaps a sorted hash table is an oxymoron. If so, what's the best way to get access to a sorted list of the things here?

Comment: You are not having a hastable (aka object) nor a proper array. If you wat to have an object you should initialize it with `{}` not with `[]`. If you initialize with `[]` you have an Array, but then do not add to it by means of `a["one"]` and `a["two"]` but by `a.push(...);`. Only after you know what data structure you want, can you bother with sorting. (BTW: `foo["bar"]` is the same as `foo.bar`, use the second, it does not clog the code with string literals and lots of square brackets)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to iterate through a hash table in JavaScript in order, make an array, populate it with the hash keys, and then sort it.

```
<html>
<body>
<pre>
  <script>
    var things = new Object ();
    things["hello"] = {"name" : "zzz I fell asleep", "number" : 7};
    things["one"] = {"name" : "something", "number" : 18};
    things["two"] = {"name" : "another thing", "number" : -2};
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in things) {
      if (things.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push(key);
      }
    }
    keys.sort ();
    for (i in keys) {
      var key = keys[i];
      var value = things[key];
      document.write (key +"="+value+"\n");
    }
  </script>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a note, the order of iteration of the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in) statement can be arbitrary, there is nothing described in the [ECMAScript specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.6.4) about the order of enumeration of the properties, it is implementation dependent... no guarantees, use with care...

Comment: @CMS: So I should use `for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)` to be strictly correct?

Comment: @Kinopiko, exactly, give a look to the following articles for more info: [ 1 ](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/) and [ 2 ](http://www.dhtmlkitchen.com/?category=/JavaScript/&date=2007/10/21/&entry=Iteration-Enumeration-Primitives-and-Objects).

Comment: You can also build your `keys` array using `Object.keys(things)`.  It's also a good practice to store the array length before the for loop's comparison step, so @CMS's for loop from above could be written like `for (var i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++)`.  This avoids repeatedly indexing into the `keys.length` property for a value that doesn't change.

Answer (score 7):

My solution

```
things.sort(function(a,b){return a.name - b.name;});
```

Comment: OP is using the array `things` incorrectly so this would not help.

Answer (score 5):

I developed a function that sorts a hash table by the key, no matter if the value is a number or a string. It keeps the key if the table is an associated table.

```
function sortHashTableByKey(hash, key_order, remove_key)
{
    var tmp = [],
        end = [],
        f_order = null;
    remove_key = remove_key || false;
    for (var key in hash)
    {
        if (hash.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
            tmp.push(hash[key][key_order]);
        }
    }
    if (hash && hash[0] && typeof(hash[0][key_order]) === 'number')
    {
        f_order = function (a, b) { return a - b; };
    }
    tmp.sort(f_order);
    function getHash(hash, value)
    {
        for (k in hash)
        {
            if (hash[k] && hash[k][key_order] === value)
            {
                return { key : k, hash : hash[k] };
            }
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0, l = tmp.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        tmp[i] = getHash(hash, tmp[i]);
        if (remove_key)
        {
            delete tmp[i].hash[key_order];
        }
        if (!hash.length)
        {
            end[tmp[i].key] = tmp[i].hash;
        }
        else
        {
            end.push(tmp[i].hash);
        }
    }
    return end;
}
```

This will do :

```
var things = new Object ();
things["hello"] = {"name" : "zzz I fell asleep", "number" : 7};
things["one"] = {"name" : "something", "number" : 18};
things["two"] = {"name" : "another thing", "number" : -2};

things = sortHashTableByKey(things, 'name');

/*
[
  two: { name: 'another thing', number: -2 },
  one: { name: 'something', number: 18 },
  hello: { name: 'zzz I fell asleep', number: 7 }
]
*/
```

Comment: @HaykSaakian, how is being the function coming along? as a human being, I really admire anyone's effort to sustain both state and function beyond the mind/body problem. bravo.

Comment: i should have said "doing this" not "being this" @ToddMorrison

Answer (score 2):

your parameters are `thing1` and `thing2`, but you're referencing some variables called `asp1` and `asp2`, which, as far as I can tell from the source you've provided, do not exist.

Also, I think what you're looking for is an associative array, which is not instantiated with the `[]` syntax. See here for more info:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

*EDIT:* I don't think there's an array in Javascript that'll let you do what you want.

You can have plain old array, which will let you do the custom sorting *or* you can have an associative array, which will let you have the named values.

With the regular array, you can obviously iterate through the indexes.

With the associative array, you can iterate through the names by doing `for (var key in myArray)`

Comment: Be careful with that for...in syntax. It'll loop over *all* the properties the object in question has, which includes things other than array keys.

Comment: ^^ This is true, but shouldn't be an issue as long as it doesn't inherit from anything.

Answer (score 0):

same as eeerahul, with keys() and String().localeCompare() :

```
function sort_by_key(t_kv,v_kv){
  return(Object.keys(t_kv).sort(
    function(a,b){return(
      String(t_kv[a][v_kv]).localeCompare(String(t_kv[b][v_kv])))}))
}

t={two:{s:'two',n:2},three:{s:'three',n:3},one:{s:'one',n:1}}
sort_by_key(t,'n')
    ["one", "two", "three"]
sort_by_key(t,'s')
    ["one", "three", "two"]
```